# how to restrict user not to check more than 5 checkboxes in asp.net checkboxes using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have 10 asp.net checkboxes in my webform i want if user select 4 checkboxes then on continue button click event it redirect to Default.aspx else if user select 6 checkboxes then click on continue button then javascript alert box will pop up and user will not redirect to default.aspx ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check it Out -->**

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox6" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox7" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox8" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox9" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox10" runat="server" /><br />
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Continue" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){

    var vCheckedCBCount =  $("input:checkbox").filter(function(index){ 
    return $(this)[0].checked == true;
    }).length;
    if(vCheckedCBCount > 5)
    {
        alert('You cannot check more than 5 check box.');
        return false;
    } 
});
```

Comment: i have to use .... 


    <script src ="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


also ???

Comment: hav u put javascript code inside $(document).ready(function(){ tag?

Comment: How can i apply this if i use web user control in asp.net ?

Comment: means you would have check box and sumit button in webusercontrol ??

Answer (score 0):

Sukhi has a nice way to do this. However, the other method would be to check each time someone clicks a checkbox to check it:

Give you checkboxes a class:

`<input type="checkbox" name="items" value="7" id="Checkbox7" class="checkme" />`

Then in jQuery:

`$(".checkme").click(function()
{`

```
if($(this).is(":checked"))
{

    if($(".checkme:checked").length > 5)
    {

        // show message
        return false;

    }

}
```

});

This will only perform the check when the user clicks checkbox and the value is "checked"

Comment: Hi Alex thanks ...but i have to use asp.net standard checkbox controls not HTL Controls